# How to reduce the height of one side of a square of a div element

Tags: html, css

I've got the following div element and I'd like the height on the right to be the number of pixels I specify e.g 5px. How can I achieve that?

Html

`<div class="square"></div>`

css

```
   .square {
     height: 14px;
     width: 14px;
     border: 2px solid #4faadf;
   }
```

Comment: just code `height: 5px;    width: 5px;`. what is this question ?

Comment: I apologize if my question is not that clear. Going by the code above we have a a square with two heights of 14px each. I'd like one to maintain a height of 14px and the other one to be 5px.

Comment: all HTML elements must fit into rectangular shapes. if you want to use other geometric shapes you must use the SVG language

Comment: I thought it was possible with HTML, will switch to SVG. Thanks.

Comment: Look into CSS clip path which works on HTML elements. You can give it a polygon path which will achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one!

```css
.square {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 5px solid #555;
    border-left: 14px solid #555;
    border-bottom: 9px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

If you want to change the right side height of the div, you should have to set that value to border-top and remove that value from the border-left value and set it to the border-bottom value. Just like below one. In here, I have set the right side height to 2px.

```css
.square {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #555;
    border-left: 14px solid #555;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: And the background color? How do you get rid to be left with just lines?

Comment: Try to change the color of the border like this.
`border-top: 5px solid #ff0000; border-left: 14px solid #ff0000;`

Comment: Changing the color to white with the default browser's background color as white, will leave you with nothing to see. I don't see how you can evade having the background color with your solution.

Comment: Can you see anything if your normal div's background color is white while you are in the default browser's background color? So in here as well, its same. If you want, you can also add a outline to this as well but it is not like adding a border to a normal div.